# Laravel 4 Sessions Not persisting with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have seen issues like this all over the web but haven't had any luck with fixes. I have a local install of laravel 4 and my sessions work great. I can login using...

```
Auth::login($user,true);
```

Then check the logged in user with...

```
Auth::check()
```

But i've found once I pushed up to my production environment which is running PHP 5.3 sessions no longer worked. To test I tried manually setting a session variable per advice from other articles and echoing it out in other another call. Again worked locally, not on prod. Has anyone ever dealt with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is your local development environment different than PHP 5.3? Are your respective development and production `php.ini` files different?

Comment: Sorry vital piece of info - My local dev environment is 5.4

Comment: forget auth. does `Session::put('foo','bar')` persists?

Comment: I am unable to access any session variable I set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the session save path on the production server and made sure its writable. Also ensure that the app/storage directory has been chmoded 777.

Relevent files to check would be php.ini

```
[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler = files

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.

;
; The path can be defined as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if
; your OS has problems with many files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle many sessions.
```

and /app/config/sessions.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',

/*
```

which points again to the storage folder potentially. I would make sure that was 777 writable, and that may clean up your problem.